# What kind mode should i use for ftp connection?Active mode or passive mode?

Tags: android, apache, ftp-client

enterLocalActiveMode(); or enterLocalPassiveMode();

i am using Apache FTP client to make a connection to a FTP server...what my app basically does is,it sends some info from phone1 to the FTP server like the Device name n stuff like that using xml and phone2 is supposed to take take that info and display it ....my problem is when the first phone is uploading the xml the second phones FTP connection protocol throws timeout exception if the connection is at the same time ...

am just wondering if phone1's Mode is set to Active and Phone2's Mode is set to passive that the exception might not happen.......any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sure, might be. Passive mode was introduced to make the 70th protocol  a little less horrible from a network points of view. So typically these days "active FTP" is only possible inside corporate networks, for all other situations "passive FTP" is far more likely to be usable, _if_ the server supports it. That said one should point out that the `FTP` protocol is a dinosaur and should be avoided wherever possible. There are far superior alternatives these days. _Unless_ none of those is offered by the service provider...

Comment: so ActiveMode is better?....oh n am connecting to a hosted FTP(am nat in the same network if i forgot to mention)

Comment: Is the above ambiguous? _"passive FTP" is far more likely to be usable_... If you use NAT on your side yourself, then obviously "active FTP" cannot work, unless you take very special precautions.

Comment: sorry didnt read it well i guess but what am i supposed to do with the timeout exception?

Comment: What do you mean with "what am i supposed to do with the timeout exception"? You cannot do anything about it, since your client fails to connect. As said above: that cannot work for obvious reasons. You can try to use "passive FTP", _if_ the server supports it. I have the impression you did not bother to understand the difference between "passive" and "active" FTP? Then I suggest you start reading about it... It is very inefficient that we should explain to you what you could try, if you do not care what the issue is about, right?